# Web API - Direct calls to different API's based on API version

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, design-patterns

Version one controllers call an existing Web API to get data.

Version two controllers need to call a new Web API to get data.

How can we change these call based on the version?

Do we need to create new service or handler to handle this? Or Is there any design pattern I can use to make changes?

Comment: In microservice architectures, the versioned service is typically a new deployable.

Comment: @DavidL Can you please explain more? Any link ?

Comment: It is not clear how the controllers are calling the web api. But simple logic will be to write code to call appropriate version of APIs in respective controllers. If URL is the only difference between the API versions then you can create a common service layer which takes URL as input, calls the Web API and returns the response content to the caller.